# CSS Multi Column Layout Margin Issue

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a css based 2 column layout...

```
.mainContentSection {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap:30px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-gap:30px; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-gap:30px;
}

.mainContentSection p {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Occasionally the top of the second column catches the margin from the bottom of the previous paragraph. This pushes down the top of the next paragraph as seen in the attached pic. I have tried break-inside, changing margins, inline-block. All have had some success, but not optimal. Can I access the second column to remove that margin?

[image]

Comment: This screenshot is taken in Chrome. This is not a situation that happens consistently. Thats why I took the snap. I have had this issue appear and disappear and reappear while I was trying to fix it. For example I changed the p display to inline-block, which sucked a whole broken p to the second column. A solution, but not one I like. I undid the display change and the problem was gone. Sooner or later it returns. I also have seen it on other sites. I have a screenshot from a different site, but cant seem to post it. It happens often enough that it is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with Safari.
Adding `display: inline-block` on the columns items solved the problem for me.

Comment: That fixed my margin issue on Firefox as well.

Answer (score 4):

The root of the issue appears to be when using `column-count` browsers treat `margin` and `padding` differently depending on whether there are an even or odd number of elements.

This means solutions like `display: inline-block; width: 100%`; or playing with `margin` or `padding` create inconsistent results.

## Solution

The only way I found to make this consistently work across browsers is to add a `parent-element` and a `spacer`. Then use `break-inside: avoid` to keep the two elements together.

#### HTML

```
<div class="mainContentSection">
  <div class="parent-element">    <!-- added this element -->
    <p>Blah blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="spacer"></div>     <!-- added this element -->
  </div>
  <div class="parent-element">   
    <p>Blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2</p>
    <div class="spacer"></div>   
  </div>

  <!-- addition items... -->

</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.mainContentSection{
  column-count:2
}
.parent-element{
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
.spacer{
  height: 10px;
}
```

You can add `padding` to `mainContentSection` or add another `spacer` above the paragraph depending where you need space.

## Problem

The inconsistent alignment appears to be is driven by `margin` and `padding` being handled differently for an even or odd number of elements. I found this to be true for `-top` and `-bottom` but to keep things simple I only use `margin-bottom` in the example.

#### Even Number of Elements (works fine)

When there's an even number of elements `margin-bottom` works.

[image]

#### Odd Number of Elements (does not work)

When there's an odd number of elements `margin-bottom` gets moved to the second column creating the misalignment.

[image]

## Other Solutions

This means that just playing with `margin` or `padding` leads to inconsistent results across browsers and devices.

Using `display: inline-block; width:100%` almost works but I found for some browser/device variations if there are only two elements it keeps the two elements in one column because there is no break. This can be addressed by adding a break as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684012/chrome-and-safari-render-css-columns-differently-when-number-of-items-equals-num) but as the user mentions it seems to have inconsistent results if element heights vary.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm a bit late to the party but as there is no accepted answer here is mine.

Before going to the point and despite it shouldn't be affecting to your problem is very much recommended to always apply both column-width and column-count values to get better responsive results.

```
columns: [minimum width] [column count]
```

Once that said, just add that your `<p>` margins (margin: 0 0 20px 0;) are totally OK, that's the way to avoid any troubles. You just have to add `break-inside: avoid;` to them and you see the magic happen.

Three thinks to take into account:

1. *Break-inside* applies to the content elements, not to the parent container
2. *Break-inside* browser compatibility relays on different formats, not only prefixes
3. *Break-inside* has issues when changing its value dynamically (e.g. from the browser's inspector panel)

Maybe those three tips were the reason why your attempts failed achieving your goal.
So the code you need is something like this:

```
.mainContentSection p {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

If you want to see a working example you can do so in this pen: https://codepen.io/elcssar/pen/dypGaWy

Comment: Except on Safari, currently. In my case, I had to also switch to padding. (If your elements have backgrounds or borders, remove their margin and wrap them in divs which have padding.)

Comment: Old Safari, previous to version 10 do not support break-inside, only the prefixed property -webkit-break-inside: auto/always, so avoid is not supported. After that version there should be no problem. However if there was, probably the display: inline-block suggested by @Robinwebdev will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use top margins on the `.mainContentSection` element, so the `margin` line would read as:   `margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;`

```
.mainContentSection {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap:30px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-gap:30px; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-gap:30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didnt affect the margin or the padding that the p was passing to the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried avoiding margin? Set `margin-bottom: 0` and introduce a transparent border for the equivalent. Say `border-bottom: 20px solid transparent` should do the trick?